# problems with the Provider using next.js and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js13

I'm having connection issues between my next-js app and redux. I just installed and created the app, and I want to 'print' the data coming from the store on my front-end.

The error tells me that I need to wrap it, but I believe I've already done that in my layout.js file.

How do I need to set up the Provider to connect the next.js and the Provider

> ⨯ node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js (37:60) @
> Provider  ⨯ TypeError: (0 ,
> _useIsomorphicLayoutEffect.useIsomorphicLayoutEffect) is not a function
> at stringify () null  ⨯ node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js (37:60) @ Provider
> ⨯ TypeError: (0 ,
> _useIsomorphicLayoutEffect.useIsomorphicLayoutEffect) is not a function
> at stringify () digest: "2458083755" null

this is my files

layout.js

```
enter code here
import './globals.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../store/store'; 

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Create Next App',
    description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <html lang="en">
                <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
            </html>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

userSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    firstName: 'joao'
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState
})

export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { userReducer } from './user/userSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer
    }
});
```

Comment: I figure out! I need to create a provider in a external file

this video helped me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Onekwb2l9zg